# group by on a left join'd column

Tags: mysql

Here is my query, it does group them by `postid` but it will not group by the project id or the `pid`

```
SELECT 
      tracker.postid as postid, 
      sum(tracker.clicks) as clicks, 
      projects.id as pid
   FROM 
      tracker_dailyclicks tracker 
         LEFT JOIN posts 
            ON tracker.postid = posts.id 
            LEFT JOIN projects 
               ON projects.id = posts.project_id
   WHERE 
          tracker.date >= '2012-03-30' 
      AND tracker.date <= '2012-03-30' 
   GROUP BY 
      postid, 
      pid 
   ORDER BY 
      clicks DESC
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, I think it has something to do with trying to group by a column that was joined from another join. Just looking for some insight.

Comment: Please try the following GROUP BY postid, projects.id

Comment: That was initially how I wrote the query but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your table structure as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tracker.postid as postid, sum(tracker.clicks) as clicks, projects.id as pid
FROM `tracker_dailyclicks` tracker 
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = postid
LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.id = posts.project_id
WHERE tracker.date >= '2012-03-30' AND tracker.date <= '2012-03-30' 
GROUP BY tracker.postid, projects.id ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

Comment: do you have postid in tracker table?

Comment: even if I simply the query to something like this `SELECT tracker.postid AS postid, sum( tracker.clicks ) AS clicks, posts.project_id
FROM tracker_dailyclicks tracker
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = postid
WHERE tracker.date >= '2012-03-30'
AND tracker.date <= '2012-03-30'
GROUP BY tracker.postid, posts.project_id
ORDER BY clicks DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30 ` it isn't grouping the project ids.

Answer (score 0):

I believer the problem you are running into is that it is a LEFT JOIN and is probably hitting NULL values.  So, whenever you have NULL values, you always can get strange side effects...  I would change to...

SELECT ... 
      COALESCE( projects.id, 0 ) as pid

Since you are already using your "pid" column alias as the group by, should have no impact there.

Comment: I think my problem is after it groups postid, it doesn't group the rows by project id because the post id's are different. Does that make sense? After I group them by post id, how do I group them by project id?

Comment: I just solved my own problem, it doesn't need to group by post id because they are related to the project id so I only need to group it by that which it does.